# How to automate locally QGIS plugin building steps using exe or script?

Tags: qgis-plugins, geoprocessing, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I have made a plugin name `Area Calc` on my local computer. The plugin work very well. I have followed  [this](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html). I don't want to release plugin. Is there any way to automate the whole above task through a script or exe which can follow all the steps required to build plugin on another computer. In short I would like to create a setup for my QGIS plugin.

Comment: Do you want to use your `Area Calc` plugin on other computers?

Comment: Yes beacuse the perosn sitting on a another computer cant install and follow all those steps

Comment: Should be enough to place that folder like in step 11 of your link if I remember correctly. Copy your Area_Calc folder from your computer to that other computer and place it inside QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins

Comment: Okay. I was thinking same . I should directly copy the folder inside plugin path and then try to reload QGIS3. I i will try this

Comment: Feel free to answer your question if this was the solution to it. It will help others having the same question.